# Could not find prepared statement with handle -1 SQL Server Profiler

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

So I have this issue where I'm running Sql Server Profiler and I'm getting hundreds(at least) of `Could not find prepared statement with handle -1`.(error 8179) per second.

I can't seem to really correlate the errors with anything specific except some cached prepared statements I think.

I'm using Linq to Sql.

If you need more info just let me know.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the solution? what setting was needed to prevent the errors?

Comment: I'm sorry it's been so long I don't recall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I figured it out.

Log4Net's AdoAdapter was keeping a prepared statement saved through the duration of its connection, and my plan cache was flushing them out sometimes.